# RStudio daily opens system default browser instead of using it's own

Tags: r, linux, browser, rstudio

Somehow my RStudio got messed up. When I'm clicking on the links in the browser, my system default browser opens, but more annoyingly it shows nothing. This also happens with the backward/forward buttons. How can I fix that?

I already tried reinstall incl. purging everything, also reboot.

[image]

### Details

```
RStudio 2023.09.0-daily+243
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
```

Comment: Looks like a confirmed bug in 2023.09 daily - https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13392

Comment: @margusl Thanks very much, solved by installing latest 2023.08!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *@margusl* noted in a comment, it's a [confirmed bug in 2023.09 daily](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13392), so downgrading to latest 2023.08 daily solved the issue. I ran into an `libssl1.1` unmet dependencies issue which had to be satisfied first. *Solution:*

```
$ wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-ide-build/electron/focal/amd64/rstudio-2023.08.0-daily-197-amd64.deb
$ wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1n-0+deb11u5_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.1n-0+deb11u5_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i rstudio-2023.08.0-daily-197-amd64.deb
```